# Activity Instance Remove from stack

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

I have several activity including TimeLine Activity. This activity start when user logged in successfully to my application. However I have a menu for theme change of my application. When I go to change application theme i does not finish Timeline activity because of next time use.
I change my theme color and background and save changes go to Timeline activity with new theme. Then when I exit my application using following code

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {
        // Ask the user if they want to quit

        new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
                .setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_alert)
                .setTitle("")
                .setMessage("Do you want to exit")
                .setNegativeButton("No", null)
                .setPositiveButton("Yes",
                        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            // @Override
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                                    int which) {
                                finish();

                                Intent intent = new Intent(
                                        Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
                                intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
                                intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                                intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
                                startActivity(intent);

                            }
                        }).show();
        return true;
    }

    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}
```

But when I start my application again I see the Timeline Activity which was before the theme change. I think Timetine activity instance retain in stack although i start new Timeline activity from ThemeChange Activity.

Activity Flow

Timeline(With Theme Black) --> ThemeChange(By pressing ThemechangeMenu) --> Change Theme and Save Button click --> Start Again TimeLine(With New Theme Successfully) --> Exit my Application Using Avobe code --> Start again my Application --> Appears TimeLine(with Balck Theme not the changed theme)

How can I destroy the previous instance of TimeLine from stack when new Timeline instance is running from Themechange activity using save button click listener?

Comment: it looks like your Application instance is being recreated. If you have an Application class than place some log statements inside OnCreate of Application class. If your application is being restarted than it will always start from the Black Theme not the one you set previously.

Comment: I have no application class.I have a reload button in timeline.If i reload the timeline then it will be changed again and i show the chaged timeline...

Answer (score 0):

place `finish();` after `startActivity(intent);` in your code and add `android:lauchMode="standard"` for the **TimeLineActivity** in the `manifest` file. Then the `activity` will not be in stack.

Comment: it should solve.. i dont know wat went wrong... but these are the two ways to resolve your problem...